# Camel + CassandraQL : Process a table without putting all in memory

Tags: memory-management, cassandra, parallel-processing, apache-camel

**Goal:** read a big Cassandra table, process line by line in parallel

**Constraints:**

- not all rows in memory
- no Spark, we have to use Camel
- One shot, no need polling the table

I did a first working version with CassandraQL but this Component seems to be limited to one query with all in memory, I did not find mechanics like fetSize/fetchMoreResult. I looked **CassandraProducer** class, **PollingConsumerPollingStrategy**, **ResultSetConversionStrategy**... See nothing.

Could it be possible to read a table by chunks of 1000 elements for example, each chunk would generate an exchange lately split in different threads ?

I think that maybe the **ProducerTemplate** injecting first exchanges in the route could be the answer. But I don't undertand how I could manage the production exchange rate to avoid to have too many rows in memory (to do so, we would need for example to check the size of the next blocking queue, if more than X no consumed elements, wait before producing more messages).

Maybe there are other options to do something like this ?
Maybe I did not see the magic parameter in CassandraQL ?
Maybe we can override some parts of CassandraQL ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be answer to be a your question but hope to kick off some discussion. But as someone learning Cassandra and spending bit of time, it made me thinking. And mainly targets `fetSize/fetchMoreResult` part of the question

**First of all, two of your constraints are contradicting**

1. Not all rows in memory

   - I don't want all them fetched at once
2. One shot, no need polling the partition

   - I don't want to go back to db more than once.

**Unless what you actually you meant is**

1. Not all rows in memory

   - I don't want all them fetched at once
2. You can go back to partition many times, as long as you go back straight to where you left it last time.

   - As long as the time it takes for the first page is same as time it takes for the second page. And the time it takes for the 19th Page is same as the time it takes for the 20th page.
   - i.e Not starting from the first row

**So I am going to assume that what you meant is Second Scenario and go with it.**

**Queries for Cassandra are going to satisfy the following two:**

1. They are going to have a restriction on clustering columns
2. They are already ordered by clustering columns

**Now Consider the following table**

- `department`(partition key), `firstName`(clustering_key), `personId`(clustering_key), `lastname`, etc as normal cols
- First query

  ```
    select department, firstName, lastname, etc
    from person
    where department = 'depart1`
    order by firstName ASC
    limit 25;
  ```
- Second query (lets say last record in the page had `userId=25` and `firstName=kavi`)

  ```
    select department, firstName, lastname, etc
    from person
    where department = 'depart1` and firstName='kavi' and userId > 25
    order by firstName ASC
    limit 25;
  ```
- As you can see, we can easily construct a Cassandra query that brings each chunk with certain size in constant time.

**Now back to integration framework**

- I remember this concept called watermark in mule where the endpoint can store and remember so that they can start from there next time. In this case, value of `userId` and `firstName`  of the last record of the last page is the watermark. So they can issue the second. I am sure we should be able to do the same with camel

I hope I have convinced that polling is not an issue where each chunk is retrieved in constant time

Comment: Yes the second scenario is the good one (polling is the default CassandraQL behaviour, and because the row are not deleted in my usecase, we would read the same things regulary unless we set repeatCount=1, that is why I mentionned that point).

I understand your example but I don't see any way of doing such a thing in Camel. We could do very weirds things like: The Cassandra component read a chunk, send a message to the next step BUT ALSO to himself with new parameters. This would let us paginate but do not solve the problem to not put all in memory anyway.

Comment: I managed to implement my own solution with the ProducerTemplate and a cassandraReader (a processor doing requests). I do not use Cassandra Component then... If no more answer in few weeks I will post it.

Comment: Yes. I looked at the component after your post and didn't see any option.So I thought if it is possible to have `timer` as the first, a processor that reads the next page to read and sets the state as the second and then `https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/dynamicRouter-eip.html` as the the and Cassandra component as the 4th